# Excel 2013: stacked bar chart with date, updating date issue

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I have a stacked bar chart, with time and duration in Excel 2013 (I'm trying to show 30 day milestones). I had no problem the first time I created the file.

Now that I need to update the dates (to have my new future 30 day milestones) the chart does not update correctly: it extends the x-axis in the future but also in the past:

[Excel file with chart](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4yLOjwRAxv7N09NZ2wwWlZ6Wjg/view?usp=sharing)

Currently, the file is from 7/15 to 8/15; when I put dates from 8/12 to 9/12, it extends the file from 5/26 to 9/23.

File is linked above, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy fix to your issue is to set the minimum and maximum values for your x-axis to the window which you want to display.

Comment: Since the OP is going to update with future events, it would probably be better to set the minimum only, allowing the max to float and include future events.